# Android error pass values Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, extra

I get an error that I do not ever, I'm passing data between an Activity.
I get this error:

```
01-07 17:14:06.063: E/AndroidRuntime(5653): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 17:14:06.063: E/AndroidRuntime(5653): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.chri.regi/conti.Elenco_c_riep}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
01-07 17:14:06.063: E/AndroidRuntime(5653):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
01-07 17:14:06.063: E/AndroidRuntime(5653):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-07 17:14:06.063: E/AndroidRuntime(5653):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-07 17:14:06.063: E/AndroidRuntime(5653):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-07 17:14:06.063: E/AndroidRuntime(5653):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-07 17:14:06.063: E/AndroidRuntime(5653):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-07 17:14:06.063: E/AndroidRuntime(5653):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-07 17:14:06.063: E/AndroidRuntime(5653):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 17:14:06.063: E/AndroidRuntime(5653):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-07 17:14:06.063: E/AndroidRuntime(5653):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-07 17:14:06.063: E/AndroidRuntime(5653):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-07 17:14:06.063: E/AndroidRuntime(5653):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-07 17:14:06.063: E/AndroidRuntime(5653): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
01-07 17:14:06.063: E/AndroidRuntime(5653):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:239)
01-07 17:14:06.063: E/AndroidRuntime(5653):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3844)
01-07 17:14:06.063: E/AndroidRuntime(5653):     at conti.Elenco_conti_riep.SaldoConti(Elenco_conti_riep.java:113)
01-07 17:14:06.063: E/AndroidRuntime(5653):     at conti.Elenco_conti_riep.onCreate(Elenco_conti_riep.java:74)
01-07 17:14:06.063: E/AndroidRuntime(5653):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
01-07 17:14:06.063: E/AndroidRuntime(5653):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-07 17:14:06.063: E/AndroidRuntime(5653):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
```

This is my code to pass:

```
tvConto.setText(d.bund+"");
        tvId.setText(d.id+"");

 list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
  @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
         Dettaglio d = dettagli.get(position);
          Intent sin_ent = new Intent(Ei.this, Enti_riep.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("id", d.id+"");
extras.putString("bund", d.bund+"");
singole_ent .putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(sin_ent);
```

This former to receive:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String id_ricevuto = (i.getStringExtra("id"));
String c_ricevuto = (i.getStringExtra("bund"));
```

Comment: Show us the full stacktrace and more code. We can't say anything with this.

Comment: Your last lines should be String id_ricevuto = extras.getString...

Comment: What does the logcat say ? Which line is throwing this exception ? What is written on this line of code ?

Comment: The logcat does not say error line, see my question at the top

Comment: @user2867831 Yes the logcat says the line. Put the full logcat please.

Comment: @user2867831 What is written on the line 113 of at `Elenco_conti_riep.java` ?

Comment: This is the line113:`Cursor c = db.rawQuery(tabella_conti, null);
   while (c.moveToNext()){
   id = c.getInt(0);
   cnto = c.getString(1);
   dat_sal = c.getString(2);
   sal = c.getFloat(3);
   
   id_conto_ricevuto.setText(id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do :

```
id_conto_ricevuto.setText(String.valueOf(id));
```

otherwise, it tries to call the method `setText(int resid)` and hence the exception.

Usually you call `setText(int resid)` when you want to set the text with a resource you defined in your `strings.xml` file, i.e `setText(R.string.myString);`.